# Was the last Animorphs book rushed?

Tags: animorphs, k-a-applegate

The Animorphs were published from 1996 to 2001, with the last book in the series being titled *The Beginning*.

I read this book when it first came out and I was really disappointed with it.  It ended somewhat abruptly, starting a new story line that it had no intention of continuing, and in general felt rushed.

Was the last book rushed to production?  If it was, why?

Comment: Note that many of the books (including all of the later ones, IIRC) were ghostwritten and not actually by Applegate. That might have some bearing on this.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah, animorphs has a lot of ghostwriters.  probably a good topic for another question

Comment: That ending *still* hurts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There's no evidence that it was, but it's hard to say.

K.A. Applegate herself claims that she had always planned to end it this way, at least in broad strokes.

> I'd always known that Animorphs would end the way it did. I knew I wanted it to end with victory, but I also knew I didn't want a clean victory. I wanted more Lord of the Rings, less Star Wars in the ending. I always admired the way Tolkien gave his characters victory, but left them with a sadder, less exciting, less enchanting world in the end.

That's a quote from the Scholastic Anibase's commentary on *Animorphs* #54, *The Beginning*.

> I couldn't have written it any other way and remained true to the respect I have always felt for Animorphs readers.

And that's a quote from [K.A. Applegate's official response](http://www.hiracdelest.com/database/articles/kaa_response-full.htm) to criticism of the ending, which is also worth a read.

So, she had the ending planned out long in advance. Did she rush into writing it out, though?

As you probably know, she wrote the first 24 books of the main 54 books in the series herself, publishing one book about every other month on average. Because of the birth of her son and difficulties in writing another series of books, beginning with book #25, most were ghostwritten, with Applegate providing outlines and editing afterwards. From book #25 to book #52, which were published just about every month, Applegate only wrote two books entirely on her own (although she did write some other, longer and more complex Animorphs-related books outside of the main continuity), before she then wrote the final two books of the series, #53 and #54.

Of course, whether or not she actually *did* rush it and phone it in is hard to say, but most of the criticized elements of the ending can be attributed to artistic choice. However, Applegate says she planned the ending in advance, and she did have a lot of time to prepare the planned ending of the series while her ghostwriters fleshed out the series.